# Make checkboxes appear and disappear

Tags: vba, ms-access

I realize that I can't use conditional formatting on checkboxes in a report. I instead added text boxes on top of the checkboxes and planned to make them visible when the one field is = "Basic Actions".  This is basically making the row look like a header.  I used conditional formatting to make the font bold.

I want to use VBA to make the textboxes appear and disappear.

```
 Private Sub Form_Load()
 Dim ba As String
 ba = "Basic Actions"

 If Form_Sub_MonSAChallenges.StandardAction.Value = ba Then
     Me.txt1.Visible = True
     Me.txt2.Visible = True
     Me.txt3.Visible = True
     Me.txt4.Visible = True

 Else
     Me.txt1.Visible = False
     Me.txt2.Visible = False
     Me.txt3.Visible = False
     Me.txt4.Visible = False
 End If

 End Sub
```

Comment: Should work as far as I see. Are you sure that the expression `Form_Sub_MonSAChallenges.StandardAction.Value = ba ` works fine? Try to debug the code.

Comment: You mention a report, but code is for a form. So?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `StandardAction` is a control on the active form, the following should suffice:

```vb
Private Sub Form_Load()
    Dim flg As Boolean
    flg = Me.StandardAction.Value = "Basic Actions"
    Me.txt1.Visible = flg
    Me.txt2.Visible = flg
    Me.txt3.Visible = flg
    Me.txt4.Visible = flg
 End Sub
```

Comment: *"This is not working at all"* does leave much to go on - do you receive any error messages?

Comment: No error message. With the code you gave, all the text boxes disappear.  If I comment out the code, they all come back and the checkboxes are hidden on all the records.  Can't seem to get it to happen for just the one record, it's all or nothing.

Comment: As I already commented to your question: It seems to belong to the condition. Try to debug your code.

Comment: I am very appreciative for all your help and interest.  I am very new to Access and VBA.  I don't understand what you mean by "belonging to a condition".  How do I fix this to where it will isolate the one record and leave the others alone?